# Только начал изучать api ботов. Решил начать с дискорда. Возникла ошибка при запуске:

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Код:

```
import discord
import asyncio


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("online")

    async def on_message(self, message): 
        if message.content.startswith("!hi"):
            await message.channel.send("Hello!")
        if message.content.find("Test Bot") != -1:
            await message.add_reaction("\N{JOYSTICK}")

client = MyClient()
client.run("Здесь токен")
```

Ошибка:

```
Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

Comment: У вас проблема подключения к серверам дискорда. Проверьте свой токен.

Comment: Токен менял. Не помогает

Comment: Попробую ещё раз

Comment: Опять использовал новый токен. Не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте обновить библиотеку: `pip install --upgrade discord`, если у вас последний на данный момент Python 3.9, то на нем дискорд работает не так гладко, как хотелось бы, попробуйте установить более раннюю версию, например, 3.8.3